# simple scenario using simplexml parser for php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

so I'm starting to use simplexml parser in the php library (5.5) .. and I thought i understood what was going ono but apparently not ... so I have an xml file that looks liek this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Data><Series>
  <Genre>|Animation|Comedy|</Genre>
  <IMDB_ID>tt0096697</IMDB_ID>
  <Language>en</Language>
  <SeriesName>The Simpsons</SeriesName>
  .
  .
  .
</Series>
<Episode>
  .
  .
</Episode>
<Episode>
  .
  .
</Episode>
</Data>
</xml>
```

now I started working with grabbing stuff inbetween the Episode tags and everything was great ... now I' am trying to get the `<SeriesName>` so in my php code :

```
$series = simplexml_load_file('en.xml');
$series_name = $series->SeriesName;
```

However this doesn't seem to work i've also tried

```
$series_name = $series->Data->Series->SeriesName
```

.. and this return the error trying to get property of non-object. I have looked at a few tutorials and can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong ... long winded i Know but I've spent some time researching with no luck, anyhelp would be awesome, as I'm sure it's something dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$series_name = $series->Data->Series->SeriesName;
```

To:

```
$series_name = $series->Series->SeriesName;
```

Comment: beautiful ... so why do i not need to step through the `<Data>` tag for  future reference?

Comment: Because data is the root tag and there can only be 1 root tag because of this you don't have to through data because you selected this already by opening the xml file. Hope that this explanation helps you a bit

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($series)` or `print_r($series)` to see contents of your SimpleXMLElement object.

Comment: okay ? how does this answer my question? ... it outputs the array that is loaded by the call `simplexml_load_file('en.xml');`

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions

```
preg_match_all('%(?<=<SeriesName>).*(?=</SeriesName>)%si', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

$result will be an array with your SeriesNames